# C# HttpWebRequest & HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#

I have a question/I need help, I'm trying to make a "updater" for my C# program, and I'm always getting this error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.WebRequest' to
>   'System.Net.HttpWebRequest'. An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

I was trying to make this "updater" as similar as possible to my .vb "updater", if anyone could help me solve this error I would be very thankful and happy, or if someone can send me a link to read about C# etc. I would also be very thankful, I'm very new to C# or the C family as well

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("link");
System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string newestversion = sr.ReadToEnd();
string currentversion = Application.ProductVersion;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at documentation for [`WebRequest.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc(v=vs.110).aspx) you will see that return type of the method is `WebRequest`, so you need to return it in your code:

```
System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string newestversion = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, you really helped me out mate, and everyone that commented on here, thank you everyone! :D

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the `System.Net.WebRequest.Create` method and cast the returned instance to `System.Net.HttpWebRequest`:

```
HttpWebRequest myReq =
    (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com/");
```

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7

Answer (score 0):

`HttpWebRequest.Create()` is actually `WebRequest.Create()`, which returns a `WebRequest`. You can cast it to `HttpWebRequest` if needed.